# Second activity called from startActivityForResult not closing

Tags: java, android

I have startActivityForResult() calling an activity called FlavorList, which is a listview populated from a database. I want, when I click on an item in the list for it to return to the activity (EditRecipe) that called it with the data. startActivityForResult() is called from a method showAddFlavorDialog() in EditRecipe which opens an alert dialog. When I click on the item in FlavorList, it just sits there and does nothing

The showAddFlavorDialog() in EditRecipe that calls startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult:

```
protected void showAddFlavorDialog(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(EditRecipe.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_recipe_flavor_alert, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditRecipe.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText percentageET = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.is_flavorpercentage);
    final TextView flavorNameTV = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.txt_flavor_name);
    final TextView flavorVendorTV = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.txt_flavor_vendor);

    final LinearLayout flavorLayout = (LinearLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.add_flavor_layout);

    flavorLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, FlavorList.class);
            request_Code = 1;
            startActivityForResult(i, request_Code);
            if(tempFlavorName != null) {
                flavorNameTV.setText(tempFlavorName);
                flavorVendorTV.setText(tempFlavorVendor);
            }

        }
    });


    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    addFlavorAlert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    addFlavorAlert.show();
}//end showAddFlavorDialog

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == request_Code)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            tempFlavorName = extras.getString("FLAVOR_NAME");
            tempFlavorVendor = extras.getString("FLAVOR_VENDOR");
            tempFlavorWeight = extras.getDouble("FLAVOR_WEIGHT");

        }
    }

}
```

The listener for the listview in FlavorList.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            _id = dbManager.getFlavorID(cursor);
            flavorName = dbManager.getFlavorName(cursor);
            flavorVendor = dbManager.getFlavorVendor(cursor);
            flavorBase = dbManager.getFlavorBase(cursor);
            flavorWeight = String.valueOf(dbManager.getFlavorWeight(cursor));

            int callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("CALLING_ACTIVITY", 0);

            switch (callingActivity) {
                case (Constants.FROM_MAIN):

                    showModifyDialog();

                    break;

                case (Constants.FROM_EDIT_RECIPE):

                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("FLAVOR_NAME", flavorName);
                    returnIntent.putExtra("FLAVOR_VENDOR", flavorVendor);
                    returnIntent.putExtra("FLAVOR_WEIGHT", flavorWeight);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    finish();

                    break;
            }//end switch-case

        }

    });
```

Comment: Add a log in your case (Constants.FROM_EDIT_RECIPE) before finish() and check where the program reaches there or not.

Comment: When you're making your intent, Intent i = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, FlavorList.class); , you're not adding an extra. Then in FlavorList you're asking for the extra "CALLING_ACTIVITY". I think int callingActivity is returning zero because the intent can't find CALLING_ACTIVITY. So your switch statement doesn't match zero and falls through. Good Luck! Try the method putExtra().

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to do the putExtra for the FROM_EDIT_RECIPE case. Checked after Muddassir pointed out to check that it go there, and saw your comment after @flobacca, but you were absolutely right.

Comment: ^ * Check Whether ** Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're making your intent, Intent i = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, FlavorList.class); , you're not adding an Extra to the intent. Then in FlavorList you're asking for the Extra "CALLING_ACTIVITY". int callingActivity is returning zero because the intent doesn't have and can't find the Extra with the key CALLING_ACTIVITY. So your switch statement doesn't match zero and falls through. Try the method putExtra() on your intent.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to put your activity in your Intent.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(context, EditRecipe.class);
```

currently you are only creating an intent `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();` which won't work until it knows where to go.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have `@Override` annotation on your `onActivityResult` method. 
Add it.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

use `getIntent` instead of create new intent.

```
 Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
```

Answer (score 0):

okey first of all you need to call you `Intent` like this,

```
Intent returnIntent  = new Intent(classname.this, EditRecipe.class);
```

and if you look at parameters of `onResultActivity`, it already provided you intent of resultant Activity, you don't have to create one, just use that one.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == request_Code)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            tempFlavorName = data.getString("FLAVOR_NAME");
            tempFlavorVendor = data.getString("FLAVOR_VENDOR");
            tempFlavorWeight = data.getDouble("FLAVOR_WEIGHT");

        }
    }

}
```

Happy Coding..